# helm chart init container with multiple commands

Tags: kubernetes-helm

we are defining a initContainer for our helm chart. relevant part is the following

```
  initContainers:
      - name: "set-volumes-init"
        image: "IMAGE AND TAG"
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'COMMAND 1 && COMMAND 2 && COMMAND 3']
        volumeMounts:
        - name: volume-summary
          mountPath: /usr/summ
```

the question is: how do i make the "command" like have the different commands according to if a value is defined or not?

e.g: if i have the value: podx.val2 defined, i want the COMMAND 2 to be included, but if its not, then i dont want it.

same for other COMMANDS

Comment: What have you already tried?  Have you read [The (Helm) Chart Template Developer’s Guide](https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide)?

Comment: I tried adding multiple "command" annotation, but i kept getting the error "key 'command' is duplicated".

in the end, since that command is bash, i added some pipes to make the commands work even if they cant find the required directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were doing this, I'd build a custom image that contained the shell script, and have it controlled by environment variables.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -n "$DO_COMMAND_2" ]; then
  command2
fi
```

The style you've written could work with a combination of YAML block syntax and Helm conditionals.  This is probably harder to maintain and test, but something like this should work:

```
command: >-
  command1
{{ if .Values.val2 }}
  && command2
{{ end }}
  && command3
```

The YAML `>-` syntax will cause everything indented after it to get folded into a single line, which helps the whitespace-control issues.

Comment: what does define the "end" of the resulting folded lane?